# Reading user input in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write nested decision structures that perform the following: If amount1 is greater than 10 and amount2 is less than 100, display the greater of amount1 and amount2.

this is what I have so far:

```
amount1=print('Enter amount1:')
amount2=print('Enter amount2:')
if amount1> 10 and amount2< 100:
    if amount1>amount2:
        print('amount1 is greater')
    elif amount2>amount1:
        print('amount2 is greater')
else:
    print('Amounts not in valid range')
```

when I run the program, this error message comes up:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Yun/Documents/untitled", line 3, in <module>
    if amount1> 10 and amount2< 100:
TypeError: unorderable types: NoneType() > int()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `print()` function returns `None`, which you store in `amount1` and `amount2`. You probably meant to use `input()` there instead:

```
amount1 = input('Enter amount1:')
amount2 = input('Enter amount2:')
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

```
amount1=raw_input('Enter amount1:')
amount2=raw_input('Enter amount2:')

if amount1> 10 and amount2< 100:
    if amount1>amount2:
        print('amount1 is greater')
    elif amount2>amount1:
        print('amount2 is greater')
else:
    print('Amounts not in valid range')
```

Comment: `raw_input` was replaced with just `input` in Python 3. http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins

Comment: @thegrinner sorry, didn't see py3k tag

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to use input instead of the print function.
2. You need to cast the variables amount1 and amount2 as an int data type.

```
    amount1=int(input('Enter amount1:'))
    amount2=int(input('Enter amount2:'))
    if amount1> 10 and amount2< 100:
        if amount1>amount2:
            print('amount1 is greater')
        elif amount2>amount1:
            print('amount2 is greater')
    else:
        print('Amounts not in valid range')
```

Answer (score 0):

Print() function returns str type value, you need to convert it into int or float type. int(print(' '))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).